# Spring boot custom annotation .. Find out where it is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Sorry for a basic question, but i have not been able to find a example for my use case.

I have a custom spring boot annotation, delivered as part of a Spring boot based JAR app, so that using the annotation my package scan is also triggered.
I now have a use case to extend my annotation with some optional parameters. 
How do I write a annotation parser where the class on which My annotation is written is not known to me.

My custom annotation looks like this,

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MySpringConfigClass.class})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface @MyCustomAnnotation {
   boolean param1() default true;
   boolean param2() default true;
}
```

Consuming application, can put this in any class, at the class level and not at method level / field level.

I need to find out where this annotation is used, and with what values.
Other use case is depending on the values, I need to generate different set of beans.

I read through various tutorials, but all examples I see are written for methods and where the class name is also known.

Can somebody please suggest an option.
Also in general I know that we have to write a class which can act as annotation parser and do activities, does Spring provide anything for writing these annotation parsers ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: suppose [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/java-annotations-tutorial-with-custom-annotation.html) post may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Rajith,
But the example in the link, knows the class on which annotation is written.
To be specific, 'com.journaldev.annotations.AnnotationExample' this class is hardcoded in the annotation parser, in my case I do not know where the annotation is written as well.

Can you suggest how to derive the class name as well dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use aspects to find all annotations and then use the logic like from Rajith Pemabandu comment.

Comment: Hi, can we use use Aspect to find out where an annotation is used. I have seen aspects on methods like before and after, in my case I need it on my custom annotation.

Can you please elaborate with an example.

Comment: Use Spring AOP annotation PCD. Here you have some examples http://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial